# How to crawl links on all pages of a web site with Scrapy

Tags: web, web-crawler, scrapy, extract

I'm learning about scrapy and I'm trying to extract all links that contains: "http://lattes.cnpq.br/andasequenceofnumbers" , example: `http://lattes.cnpq.br/0281123427918302`
But I don't know what is the page on the web site that contains these information.
For example this web site:

```
http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/
```

The links that I want are on this page:

```
http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/?page_id=697
```

What could I do?
I'm trying to use rules but I don't know how to use regular expressions correctly.
Thank you

## 1 EDIT----

I need search on all pages of the main (ppgcc.ufv.br) site the kind of links `(http://lattes.cnpq.br/asequenceofnumber)`. My Objective is get all the links lattes.cnpq.br/numbers but I don't know where they are. I'm using a simple code actually like:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["ppgcc.ufv.br"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/',
    )
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*']), follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'@href']), callback='parse')]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = str(random.randint(1, 9999))
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

#I'm trying to understand how to use rules correctly
```

## 2 EDIT----

Using:

```
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = [".ppgcc.ufv.br"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/',
    )
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*']), follow=True),
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'@href']), callback='parse_links')]
    def parse_links(self, response):
        filename = "Lattes.txt"
        arquivo = open(filename, 'wb')
        extractor = LinkExtractor(allow=r'lattes\.cnpq\.br/\d+')
        for link in extractor.extract_links(response):
            url = link.urlextractor = LinkExtractor(allow=r'lattes\.cnpq\.br/\d+')
            arquivo.writelines("%s\n" % url)                
            print url
```

It shows me:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\tutorial3>scrapy crawl example
2015-06-02 08:08:18-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.6 started (bot: tutorial3)
2015-06-02 08:08:18-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-06-02 08:08:18-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial3.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial3
.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial3'}
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState

2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMidd
leware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMidd
leware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLe
ngthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/> (referer: None)
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.cgu.gov.br': <GET http://www.cgu.gov.br/acessoainformacao
gov/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.brasil.gov.br': <GET http://www.brasil.gov.br/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ppgcc.ufv.br': <GET http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ufv.br': <GET http://www.ufv.br/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.dpi.ufv.br': <GET http://www.dpi.ufv.br/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.portal.ufv.br': <GET http://www.portal.ufv.br/?page_id=84
>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.wordpress.org': <GET http://www.wordpress.org/>
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 215,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 18296,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 2, 11, 8, 19, 912000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'offsite/domains': 7,
         'offsite/filtered': 42,
         'request_depth_max': 1,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 2, 11, 8, 19, 528000)}
2015-06-02 08:08:19-0300 [example] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And I was looking the source code of the site, there are more links of pages that the crawl didn't GET, maybe my rules are incorrect

Comment: You want to extract those links or you want to follow those links? Depending on what you want, you need to handle it differently.

Comment: Also, if you know all the links you want are in the page `http://www.ppgcc.ufv.br/?page_id=697`, you can just use that in `start_urls`.

Comment: Maybe if you paste your code, we can help you more easily.

Comment: colega vi que vc é br, então fica mais facil de nos comunicarmos.... é o seguinte, preciso dos links "lattes" porem eu nao sei em qual pagina do site eles estão pois no final vou repetir todo o processo para varios sites entende? sites de universidades que nao possuem o mesmo padrao, entao minha ideia era pegar todos os links lattes.cnpq.br/numeros que eu encontrar dentro de qualquer pagina do site

Comment: oi, Bruno! :) Listen, it's not very polite to write in Portuguese here (the content is supposed to be helpful for other people too). You can ask the question in Portuguese in Stackoverflow em Português: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/scrapy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, a couple things first:

1) the `rules` attribute only works if you're extending the `CrawlSpider` class, they won't work if you extend the simpler `scrapy.Spider`.

2) if you go the `rules` and `CrawlSpider` route, you should not override the default `parse` callback, because the default implementation is what actually calls the rules -- so you want to use another name for your callback.

3) to do the actual extraction of the links you want, you can use a [`LinkExtractor`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) inside your callback to scrape the links from the page:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...

    def parse_links(self, response):
        extractor = LinkExtractor(allow=r'lattes\.cnpq\.br/\d+')
        for link in extractor.extract_links(response):
            item = LattesItem()
            item['url'] = link.url
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm close, but look the edition again, maybe my rules are incorrect

Comment: @BrunoCarazato I believe you'd be okay with just one rule: `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*']), callback='parse_links',  follow=True)`

Comment: @BrunoCarazato This tells Scrapy: "just follow every link for that is in the domain, calls parse_links for it and keep applying this rule for every page"

Comment: Its Works great! Thank you!
EDIT- The output give all the links I need but one or two are in this way=
"http://www.saudecoeste.ufms.br/%20http://lattes.cnpq.br/4903660157313116" and not just "http://lattes.cnpq.br/4903660157313116"

Comment: @BrunoCarazato that looks like a problem in the HTML page. maybe there is an space in the link `href=" http...."`? I guess you'll have to do some post-processing for that case.

Comment: Elias, I have a problem, If some page have a link to another page that has been already crawled, it will crawl again and I will have a lot of same results.

Comment: Hi @BrunoCarazato -- the usual procedure is to open a new question (so that there aren't big chats here). Scrapy filter duplicated pages based on URLs, so you probably shouldn't be duplicate pages scraped.