# Scraping/crawling multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Up to now I have found how to scrape one page or multiple pages with same url, but changing number. However, I could not find how to scrape pages with subcategories and their subcategories and finally get the content needed.
I am trying to scrape this website: http://www.askislam.org/index.html
I am using Scrapy, but I do not know where to start.
Or you can suggest a better option, I just use python and check from there.

Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders                 import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors          import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders                 import Spider
from scrapy                         import Selector
from ask_islam.items                import AskIslamItem
from scrapy.http                    import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors          import LinkExtractor
import  re

class AskislamSpider(Spider):
    name = "askislam"
    allowed_domains = ["askislam.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.askislam.org/']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ()), callback = 'parse', follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        links = hxs.css('div[id="categories"] li a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            url = 'http://www.askislam.org' + link.replace('index.html', '')
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        categories = hxs.css('div[id="categories"] li').extract()
        questions = hxs.xpath('a').extract()
        if(categories):
            for categoryLink in categories:
                url = 'http://www.askislam.org' + categoryLink.replace('index.html', '')
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)
                # print (question)
```

**EDIT**

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request("http://www.askislam.org", callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    categories = hxs.css('#categories li')
    for cat in categories:
        item = AskIslamItem()
        link = cat.css('a::attr(href)').extract()[0]
        link = "http://www.askislam.org" + link

        item['catLink'] = link

        logging.info("Scraping Link: %s" % (link))

        yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_page)
        yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_categories)

def parse_categories(self, response):
    logging.info("The Cat Url")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580974/how-to-crawl-links-on-all-pages-of-a-web-site-with-scrapy

Comment: It might be helpful to give some code of what you are able to scrape. It's easier for other people to elaborate on existing code than creating a complete spider for you.

Answer (score 1):

Read links from that http://www.askislam.org/index.html page using xPath or CSS Selectors of those sub-categories and then do another `Request()`

**EDIT:**

```
import logging

class AskislamSpider(Spider):

    name = "askislam"

    def start_requests(self):

        yield Request("http://www.askislam.org/", callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        categories = response.css('#categories li').extract()
        for cat in categories:
            link = cat.css("a::attr(href)").extract()[0]
            link = "http://www.askislam.org/" + link

            logging.info("Scraping Link: %s" % (link))

            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: But wouldnt that only iterate the subcategory once?
What I want to do is follow the links until a div tag with id=categories does not exist on the page.

Comment: USE selectors to see if `div#categories` exists, if it does, then make another `Request()` ... thats it .. BTW you should post some code that you have tried ... otherwise we cant help

Comment: @AssabAmad see I added code in my answer, just copy paste and it should work

Comment: Thank it worked. I am now trying to follow these links and get detail information about it. Is it possible to yield multiple requests in the function?

`yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_page)`
`yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_categories)`

Comment: Yes its possible to yield multiple requests ... you can yield as many request as you want ... PLEASE ACCEPT ANSWER .. and UPVOTE

Comment: Is there any error? or what? and what you are doing in `parse_categories` method?

Comment: in this line `logging.info("Scraping Link: %s" % (link))` you already have Category Link so why are you `yield`ing to `parse_categories`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hasahmad/c08b2196b0ff1fd8dca923c7f97e1cda#file-scrapy-askislam-log-L134

Comment: Bro what you want to do actually? Dont you want to get links of all categories? its exactly what its doing ...